# linq to sql in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables in SQLCe Database:

```
Id          text
1            hello
2            help
```

here code i to get text field and speech it. but it's not working:

```
int d=1;
private async void btplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

var query = 
from c in db.TBListen 
where c.Id == d
select c.text;
String text = query.ToString();
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
await synth.SpeakTextAsync(text);
}
```

Questions are :
how do i select random text in database and speech it

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` on your LINQ is most likely to serialise the statement. I would suggest forcing the SQL execution with something like `.FirstOrDefault()`.

however, your code doesn't provide any information about your DAL (what is the `db` field type, for example?).